# jQuery: How to select form elements for the current clicked button?

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/3/

**Requirement**

Every form has bunch of dynamic data like video id, title, views, that I want to send to backend depending on which button "New" clicked

How can I do that?

The fiddle is to correctly alert the title for the video, for example

Answer (score 0):

Just select the parent form and from there you can select some other element in the form

```
$(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('.create-playlist-button', $(this).closest('form')).prop('disabled', val.length == 0);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/5/

Comment: the alert is gone :(, can you give me some examples?

Comment: can you give me some example with alert boxes?

Comment: @daydreamer I don't know what alert boxes will do, but here you go http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/19/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `.closest()`

like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('.view-item').find('.title').html());
});
```